# Code works on page-example.php by not category-example.php

Tags: php, categories, ajax, page-template, html

For my category page for food I originally had it on category-food.php however the code wasn't working properly. I had trouble figuring out why until I pasted the code onto another php file, page-food.php. The code ended up working on the page-food.php.  Does anyone have a reason for why this is the case, and how I can get it to work on category-food.php?

*the main issue was that on the category-food.php my ajax load more button would not show up. But on page-food.php the ajax load more button showed up and worked perfectly. This is the plugin I am using for that - https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-load-more/

the code...

```html
<?php
get_header();
get_template_part ('inc/carousel-food');

$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1),
    'cat' => 10,
 ));

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    // display #ajax wrapper only if we have posts
    echo '<div id="ajax"><div class="row">';
    $i = 0;
    while($the_query->have_posts()) {
          $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                <?php
                   if($i % 3 == 0) {
                     echo '</div><div class="row">';
                   }
                ?>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <article <?php post_class(); ?> >
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                            <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                            <p class="post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                            <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                            <?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?>
                    </article>
                </div>

    <?php $i++; }//end while

    echo '</div></div>'; // close the #ajax wrapper after the post list

    if(get_query_var('paged') < $the_query->max_num_pages) {
        load_more_button();
    }


} else { // if there are no posts

    echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';

}//end if

get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: What happens if you manually visit each page, like `/category/food/page/2/`, etc.? Do those pages work?

Comment: I have a load more button. So when a user clicks it the posts load underneath the button and don't get to a new page.

Comment: I understand that, but what I'm getting at is, how does `load_more_button` decide when there's more to load? You're creating a new query in the template, `$the_query`, I'll take a wild guess and say that `load_more_button` is operating on the global `$wp_query`, aka the Main Query.

Comment: I'm still getting the hang of wordpress, so I didn't quite pickup on everything you said. What files should I be looking at, or how could I change the query location?